# Since Microservices are hailed as transformative, why weren't Microservices done in the computing early days? What specifically enabled Microservices?

Tags: microservices

I came from a monolithic world and am finding microservices architecture very refreshing and revolutionary.

Since Microservices are hailed as transformative, as opposed to the boring monolithic (no one will get a pay raise from proposing to their manager a monolithic architecture), why weren't Microservices proposed in the earlier days of computing?

Going beyond the usual marketing terms we hear (cloud native, containers, agile), what specifically changed in the recent years that enabled Microservices to take off?

Comment: *no one will get a pay raise from proposing to their manager a monolithic architecture*  Oh, hang around long enough (maybe 10 years, certainly no longer) and the pendulum will swing back.  Fads and fashions come and go in computing, as in, well, every other aspect of human society.

Comment: Wait, what? Suggesting Microservices is worth a raise? By that logic, a *lot* of the developers I got to know so far should be millionaires. And if someone who gives raises for such things is in control then microservices won't save you

Comment: `Microservices are hailed as transformative` -- Who's saying that?  I'll bet they said the same thing about SOA and CORBA when they first came out.  What are those, you ask?  Exactly.

Answer (score 4):

Microservices have technical and social aspects:

- each microservice can be *developed* and *deployed* independently
- each microservice can *scale* independently

For each of these aspects – development, deployment, scaling – it took some time until microservices became a sensible option.

Most problems then and now are simply not so big that scaling would be a concern. And long ago, the cheapest way to scale was not to build distributed systems but to build bigger machines. What has changed since then: now we are solving many more problems with computers, in particular internet-related stuff, and quite a few problems have performance requirements that cannot be satisfied by a single blade server. Bigger machines are not an option beyond some point due to physical limits. So distributed systems it is.

As a sub-point of this, distributed systems can be attractive because they are potentially more highly-available. This doesn't imply microservices as a monolithic architecture can be made HA as well, but microservices are a popular way to build highly available systems.

Microservices aren't necessary for a system to scale, but it allows different parts of a system to scale *independently*. For example, some web app might need a different number of frontend servers, database replicas, and worker nodes for optimally cost-effective performance.

Software development used to be release-oriented: requirements go in on one side of the process, developers do their thing, and some time later a release emerges on the other side. Such a view causes difficulties if requirements are uncertain and need to be tested by putting them into practice, if there is ongoing maintenance without clear releases, or if the project is simply very big so that it's ineffective and too risky to release all components together.

The dot-com bubble shifted priorities towards minimizing time to market. “Rapid Application Development” was a big thing. Agile techniques emphasized iteration and early deployment. One of the most influential agile techniques were things like automated unit testing, continuous integration, and (much later) continuous deployment. DevOps builds upon these agile ideas and suggests a strong focus on making deployments automated.

All of this is relevant for a service architecture because services can be modified and deployed independently so that changes reach production faster. That involves a lot more total deployments than for a monolithic architecture, so that automated build and deployment systems are a prerequisite. Independent development also means that different services can be built with different technology stacks, as long as the services can communicate via some common interface.

Containers are not necessary for microservices, but containers simplify system administration and container images make automated deployment a lot easier. Similarly, “the cloud” is not necessary for microservices. But a microservice system does need a cluster of machines to run on, and cloud platforms are an easy low-capex way to get that cluster.

Microservices represent the current best practice for developing large systems that need independent development, deployment, and scaling. This is based on the currently known technologies and development techniques.

However, microservices are not the first occurrence of service-based architectures. Before that, service-oriented architectures (SOA) were already popular, especially in an enterprise context. SOA and microservices have overlapping goals and techniques, but SOA tends to be about integration of different services over a common message bus/queue. Microservices are an evolution of SOA, but may favour more fine-grained services and don't necessarily have a centralized message queue.

Microservices will also not be the last occurrence of these ideas. Now that the microservice hype is dying down they are becoming an ordinary tool in the system architect's toolbox, but our technologies and techniques continue to evolve. Interesting directions include scaling *down* with FaaS, and moving computations to the data with edge computing.

Answer (score 1):

The number one thing that enabled micro services popularity was that it became trivial to deploy a web server. In some languages it only takes a few lines. This enabled rapid REST prototypes and even enabled security through https.

A very close second is the rise of [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). Not having to go to a central place to get a unique ID allows much more distribution in the design than was ever possible before.

Monolithic applications tend to trap you in a single language using a single address space on a single computer. Micro services use URLs instead and as long as the data is compatible you don't care what language is used on the other side.

Monolithic applications enforce a uniformity that some find pleasing. The advantages of moving away from that haven't always been understood. Encouraging developers to use monoliths makes it easier to capture developers. Something large companies eager to keep you on their platform try very hard to do.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply it didn't make sense without virtualization (in the x86 domain) and easy and quick infrastructure provisioning.

I still know some clients where setting up an application instance involves planning and sign-off by infrastructure team (a month or so), physical acquisition of server hardware (up to *several* months), provisioning for obligatory test and redundancy systems (which means you need at least 4 of everything, always!), handover to operations team (again a month). You'll want to literally cram as much things as you can into one "installation" to avoid this process as much as you can. This was more or less the norm when I started in the 90s.